# Windows 10 File Explorer sidebar shows 'Desktop'

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
<sup>**The first screenshot shows what I have. The second screenshot shows what I want.**</sup>

Can you show me?

The sidebar only shows Desktop and under desktop I must find the correct place 'Network, This PC, etc.' I want it to only show Network, This PC, Homegroup and such. I want them to be on the highest level of the tree view, not under Desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tried this on my Windows 10 Laptop and found that right clicking in the area on which you are focusing (Left sidebar of the explorer) and unchecking `Show All Folders` changes the layout to what you are looking for.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @CoffeeToCodeMachine If this was the solution and it worked for you, then please mark it as the answer so it is able to help other users as well. Thanks. :)